# Spectral radius inequality for products of M-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an inverse M-matrix $A$, a diagonal nonnegative matrix $D$, and let $C = D^{-1} A D A^T$. In simulations I always find that $\rho(C) < \rho(A) ^2$. Could it be that this is a general property of inverse M-matrices?

Comment: What are M matrices?

Answer (score 1):

No, the reverse (non-strict) inequality is true, and it has nothing to do with $M$-matrices. Let $S=D^{1/2}$. Then
\begin{aligned}
\rho(C)
&=\rho(D^{-1}ADA^T)\\
&=\rho(S^{-1}AS^2A^TS^{-1})\\
&=\|S^{-1}AS\|_2^2\\
&\ge\rho(S^{-1}AS)^2\\
&=\rho(A)^2.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Consider the following example. $C = D^{-1} D A^T$, with $D = diag(100,1)$ and $A = (I-B)^{-1}$ with $B$ given by $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0.3 & 0.3 \\
    0.1 & 0.1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ I get that $\rho(C) = 2.39 < \rho(A) ^ 2 = 2.79$.

Comment: Even ignoring the $D$ matrix, in simulations I am getting $\rho(AA^T) < \rho(A)^2$, which I understand is not possible. Consider $A$ given by $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0.5 & 0.2 \\
    0.1 & 0.2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ I get that $\rho(AA^T) = 0.25 < \rho(A)^2 = 0.31.$ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Andres Octave (a Matlab clone) gives $\rho(C)=5.92>2.79=\rho(A)^2$ in your first example and $\rho(AA^T)=0.320>0.309=\rho(A)^2$ in the second example.

Comment: Also, in the second example, you may calculate $P=AA^T$ by hand and get $p_{11}=0.29$. Since $P$ is symmetric, $\rho(P)=\|P\|_2\ge|p_{11}|=0.29$. It is impossible that $\rho(P)=0.25$.